# Where to find good RDoc documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, rdoc

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to document my application. To do that I would to find some "good" documentation about **RDoc**.

Where I can find that? That is, what are "the best" web resource where to find documentation about **RDoc**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference on the markup](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Markup.html) used in rdoc is quite good but really hard to find.

Comment: I also updated the rdoc wiki article to point directly to the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try some of the links referenced here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648703/good-tutorials-on-how-to-use-rdoc